# A norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\partial C$ is the unit sphere?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, normed-spaces

Suppose we are on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume that $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a convex bounded neighborhood of the origin invariant by central symmetry.

Let $\partial C$ denote the boundary of $C$. My question is :

> Can we find a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\partial C$ is the unit sphere ? Moreover, is it unique?

This is question arises after reading my course, but I can not find a satisfactory 'solution'.

Comment: Have you heard of Minkowski functionals?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes I heard about that.

Comment: Could the Minkowski functional of $C$ have anything to do with it?

Comment: @DanielFischer Hum I am tempted to use this result : Let $C$ be a closed convex containing 0 in a finite-dimensional space. Then $C$ is bounded if and only if the gauge does not take the value $0$ outside the origin. Is it helpful ?

Comment: Yes, that says that the Minkowski functional of $C$ is a norm and not only a seminorm.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah right. Thank you. Do you think we have uniqueness?

Comment: Sure. A norm is determined by its unit sphere.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, It slipped my mind. Thank you again to answering my question. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C$ is a convex and balanced (symmetric) neighbourhood of $0$. Since it's a neighbourhood of $0$, it is absorbing, hence the Minkowski functional

$$\mu_C \colon x \mapsto \inf \left\{ t > 0 : x \in t\cdot C\right\}$$

of $C$ is finite everywhere. Since $C$ is convex, it is a sub-norm (subadditive, positive homogeneous, and non-negative), and since $C$ is balanced, it is a seminorm. Since $C$ is bounded, $\mu_C$ is a norm.

The open unit ball of $\mu_C$ is the interior of $C$, and the closed unit ball of $\mu_C$ is the closure of $C$, hence the unit sphere of $\mu_C$ is the boundary $\partial C$ of $C$.

The uniqueness follows since a norm is determined by its unit sphere.

It may be worth pointing out that nothing in the argument is specific to $\mathbb{R}^2$ or even the finite-dimensionality. For any convex, balanced and bounded neighbourhood $C$ of $0$ in a normed space $E$, the Minkowski functional $\mu_C$ is a norm that is equivalent to the norm we started with ($\mu_C$ is continuous since $C$ is a neighbourhood of $0$, and the topology induced by $\mu_C$ is at least as fine as the original since $C$ is bounded), whose unit sphere is $\partial C$.

Comment: In fact the proof work for all normed vector space, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And the norm $\mu_C$ is equivalent to the norm we started with under the hypotheses.

Comment: Indeed. Well, I've learned something new today. (+1).

Comment: @DanielFischer How can I prove that $x \in t.C \Longrightarrow i.x \in t.C$ ?
If we are on the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space espace,the square of vertex  $1; i; -1; -i$ satisfies the conditions imposed on $C$ but the application $U_{C}$ does not check $$U_C(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}.1) = |e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}|U_C(1)$$.

Comment: @Edwin The meaning of balanced depends on the scalar field. We can uniformly define it as "$B$ is balanced if (and only if) $x\in B$ implies $\lambda x\in B$ for all $\lambda$ with $\lvert\lambda\rvert\leqslant 1$". Thus an $\mathbb{R}$-balanced subset of a complex vector space is generally not $\mathbb{C}$-balanced. The square with vertices $\pm 1,\pm i$ is $\mathbb{R}$-balanced, but not $\mathbb{C}$-balanced, it is not the unit ball of any (semi)norm on $\mathbb{C}$ viewed as a complex vector space.

Comment: Sorry I am confused about english notation here, does 'invariant by central symmetry'=balanced ?

Comment: I suppose "invariant by central symmetry" means $C = (-1)\cdot C$. Then no, it's not the same. In an $\mathbb{R}$ vector space however, a convex set $C$ is balanced if and only if $C = (-1)\cdot C$. That is not so for complex vector spaces. But since the question was about $\mathbb{R}^2$, I assumed that viewed as a real vector space. For complex spaces, you need $e^{i\varphi}\cdot C = C$ for all real $\varphi$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. A last question (I am sorry if I am losing your time). For the general case how can we prove that the interior of $C$  is included on the open unit ball of $U_{C}$ ? On $\mathbb{R}2$ is pretty easy : There was always a triangle containing a ball centered at a point in the interior of $C$ itself included in $C$ by convexity, but I do not know how to bring a plane in the general case.

Comment: If $x\in C^\circ$, then so is $t\cdot x$ for some $t > 1$ by continuity of $t\mapsto t\cdot x$. Thus $x\in t^{-1}C$ and $\mu_C(x) \leqslant t^{-1} < 1$, so $x$ is in the open unit ball of $\mu_C$.